# C# ComboBox in DataGridView with valuemember and displaymember

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

I would like to ask you for help with my problem. I have a DGV where every column is set with DataPropertyName from List<>. When I load it, DGV is filled with Ids of shifts. It works perfectly, but I want to change this (cell with int) to ComboBox, where displaymember will be shift name and valuemember this shift ID.

Does anybody have any solution or I should remake it?

Thank you very much

this is code I have

```
 public void FillWithData(int month, int year, int centerID)
    {
        IScheduleRecord record = new ScheduleRecordDAO();

        List<Shift> shifts = new ShiftDAO().GetShiftsByCenterId(center);

        dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "Day1";
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "Day2";
        dataGridView1.Columns[3].DataPropertyName = "Day3";
        dataGridView1.Columns[4].DataPropertyName = "Day4";
        dataGridView1.Columns[5].DataPropertyName = "Day5";
        dataGridView1.Columns[6].DataPropertyName = "Day6";
        dataGridView1.Columns[7].DataPropertyName = "Day7";
        dataGridView1.Columns[8].DataPropertyName = "Day8";
        dataGridView1.Columns[9].DataPropertyName = "Day9";
        dataGridView1.Columns[10].DataPropertyName = "Day10";
        dataGridView1.Columns[11].DataPropertyName = "Day11";
        dataGridView1.Columns[12].DataPropertyName = "Day12";
        dataGridView1.Columns[13].DataPropertyName = "Day13";
        dataGridView1.Columns[14].DataPropertyName = "Day14";
        dataGridView1.Columns[15].DataPropertyName = "Day15";
        dataGridView1.Columns[16].DataPropertyName = "Day16";
        dataGridView1.Columns[17].DataPropertyName = "Day17";
        dataGridView1.Columns[18].DataPropertyName = "Day18";
        dataGridView1.Columns[19].DataPropertyName = "Day19";
        dataGridView1.Columns[20].DataPropertyName = "Day20";
        dataGridView1.Columns[21].DataPropertyName = "Day21";
        dataGridView1.Columns[22].DataPropertyName = "Day22";
        dataGridView1.Columns[23].DataPropertyName = "Day23";
        dataGridView1.Columns[24].DataPropertyName = "Day24";
        dataGridView1.Columns[25].DataPropertyName = "Day25";
        dataGridView1.Columns[26].DataPropertyName = "Day26";
        dataGridView1.Columns[27].DataPropertyName = "Day27";
        dataGridView1.Columns[28].DataPropertyName = "Day28";

        if (CountColumns(month, year) == 30) {
            dataGridView1.Columns[29].DataPropertyName = "Day29";
            dataGridView1.Columns[30].DataPropertyName = "Day30";
        }
        if (CountColumns(month, year) == 31) {
            dataGridView1.Columns[29].DataPropertyName = "Day29";
            dataGridView1.Columns[30].DataPropertyName = "Day30";
            dataGridView1.Columns[31].DataPropertyName = "Day31";
        }

        dataGridView1.DataSource = record.GetScheduleRecordsByMonthYearCenter(month, year, center);
        this.dataGridView1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Beige;
        this.dataGridView1.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor =
            Color.LightGray;
        this.dataGridView1.Columns["Year"].Visible = false;
        this.dataGridView1.Columns["Month"].Visible = false;
        this.dataGridView1.Columns["CenterID"].Visible = false;
        this.dataGridView1.Columns["Id"].Visible = false;
        this.dataGridView1.Columns["EmployeeID"].Visible = false;
        if (CountColumns(month, year) == 28)
        {
            this.dataGridView1.Columns["Day29"].Visible = false;
            this.dataGridView1.Columns["Day30"].Visible = false;
            this.dataGridView1.Columns["Day31"].Visible = false;
        }
        if (CountColumns(month, year) == 30)
        {
            this.dataGridView1.Columns["Day31"].Visible = false;
        }
```

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a helper method in one of my apps to add DataGridViewComboBoxColumn controls. Hopefully it can help you get where you need to:

```
    private void AddBoundDataGridViewComboBoxColumn(
        DataGridView dgv,
        string dataPropertyName,
        string displayMember,
        string valueMember,
        object dataSource,
        string headerText,
        string toolTipText = "")
    {
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboBoxColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        int columnIndex;
        if (ts.TraceVerbose) Trace.WriteLine("entering");
        try
        {
            #region Try
            comboBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = dataPropertyName;
            comboBoxColumn.Name = dataPropertyName;
            comboBoxColumn.DisplayMember = displayMember;
            comboBoxColumn.ValueMember = valueMember;
            comboBoxColumn.DataSource = dataSource;
            columnIndex = dgv.Columns.Add(comboBoxColumn);
            dgv.Columns[columnIndex].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            dgv.Columns[columnIndex].HeaderText = headerText;
            dgv.Columns[columnIndex].ToolTipText = toolTipText;
            if (ts.TraceVerbose) Trace.WriteLine("Column added to " + dgv.Name + ": " + dataPropertyName + " (Tool tip: " + toolTipText + ")");
            #endregion Try
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (ts.TraceVerbose) Trace.WriteLine("exiting");
        }
    }
```

I then use a generic event handler for the cell content click:

```
        private void dgvSCXTableView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;

        if (senderGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewComboBoxColumn && e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps you. If you post your implementation of Shift in the following line that may help:

```
List<Shift> shifts = new ShiftDAO().GetShiftsByCenterId(center);
```